# How to calculate an average in SQL excluding zeroes?

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the average of a column of numbers, but i want to exclude the rows that have a zero in that column, is there any way this is possible?
The code i have is just a simple sum/count:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1)/Count(Column1) AS Average
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(Column1) FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 <> 0
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is `AVG()` and `CASE`/`NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(Column1, 0)) as Average
FROM table1;
```

Average ignores `NULL` values. This assumes that you want other aggregations; otherwise, the obvious choice is filtering.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple roads lead to Rome...

```
select sum(Column1) / sum( case Column1
                           case 0 then 0 else 1
                           end )
from table1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT AVG(column) FROM TABLE
where column **not like** '0%'
```